# Python module for drawing functions graphics

Tags: python, graphics

Which python module should I use for drawing simple functions graphics?

E.g

f: M -> M, f(x) = x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the third party Gnuplot-py package. I have used it before with success.

If you are familiar with gnuplot syntax, this should be relatively easy. If not, there are plenty of good gnuplot examples online.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gnuplot-py/1.8